# AWS CloudWatch Metrics directly to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to get CloudWatch Metrics directly into S3? I don't need logs but ELB Metrics. I would like them logged to S3 on a regular basis (ideally as CSV).

Right now, I'm thinking of writing my own script to do it, but maybe there's there's an automatic way to put it in S3 (or Redshift)?

Comment: What ELB metrics are you specifically interested in?

Comment: `RequestCount` mainly.

Answer (score 3):

CloudWatch itself does not have a native export feature that will send data periodically to S3.

As you suggest, you would need to develop a scrip tthat pulls the CloudWatch metrics that you wish to store (in this case ELB metrics) using the AWS CLI and copy those metrics to your S3 bucket on a regular basis.

Using the [get-metric-statistics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html) command, the script would get the statistics for the specified metric, and store the data to your S3 bucket

See also [Elastic Load Balancing Dimensions and Metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-metricscollected.html)